# Easiest way to read PDF(/A) metadata from a Delphi app?

Tags: delphi, pdf, metadata

For [PDF/A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) documents which contain additional information (like barcode data) in their embedded metadata, is there a simple way to access this information from a Delphi application - instead of using a full-featured PDF reader / writer application library? (For example open source command line tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the PDF metadata is just available in plain text in the PDF/A document.

So you can search for the `<x:xmpmeta` pattern in the file, then the whole metadata is available here, until `</x:xmpmeta>`. Then you retrieve the XML content.

```
function ExtractPDFMetadata(const aPDFFileName: TFileName): UTF8String;
var tmp: RawByteString;
    i: integer;
begin
  with TFileStream.Create(aPDFFileName,fmOpenRead) do 
  try
    SetLength(tmp,Size);
    Read(tmp[1],Size);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  result := '';
  i := pos('<x:xmpmeta',tmp);
  if i=0 then exit;
  delete(tmp,1,i-1);
  i := pos('</x:xmpmeta>',tmp);
  if i=0 then exit;
  result := copy(tmp,1,i+12);
end;
```

Then this UTF8String could be used to parse the XML content, as usual.

You can also locate this XML content using the "Metadata" kind of entry in the PDF catalog: this will be faster (don't have the parse the file), but will need much extra coding.

Comment: Thanks! A streaming XML (SAX) parser would be handy here :)

Comment: Please note that the metadata could be compressed by zlib or any other PDf stream Filter. The documentation states: The contents of a metadata stream is the metadata represented in Extensible Markup Language (XML). This information is visible as plain text to tools that are not PDF-aware only if the metadata stream is both unfiltered and unencrypted. Also: the PDF/A standard does not specify that this stream should be left uncompressed --> Thus: This might not work for all PDF/A documents.

Comment: AFAIK in order to be valid, the XML metadata should not be compressed, according to the PDF/A standard. At least, some PDF/A validators expect this.

Comment: @Arnaud: I never saw one with a compressed Metadata stream but the standard states: 6.1.5 Document information dictionary
A document information dictionary may be defined in a conforming file. If defined, its elements shall be
consistent with analogous XMP metadata properties as specified in 6.7.3. and together with the PDF standard it is possible to use the FlateDecode stream filter..